# How to create a good topology from SVG for 2D animation?

Tags: modeling

I have only the outline drawn as a vector in svg file. [Click here to view.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Outline_of_a_bunny.svg) I import it to blender. It becomes a path. I convert it to a mesh.

Now, I would like to subdivide it and have it in a good topology (square faces or quads) so that I can animate it.

I tried many things but they  don't work such as: Right Click and subdivide > Adding subdiv surface modifier....etc.

How can I do it, please?

Why do I want to do this? Because I have a colorful png image and I want to simply animate it with bones. Just like what happens in After Effects.

Comment: For such a thing I would filled the outline by delaunay triangulation ... I just can't remind me what addon he this as a side function that I work with few weeks ago ...

Comment: @vklidu Come on! Try to remember man. Go to the files of your project and you may be able to find it.

Comment: There is a remesh tool built in Blender but you're better off using specific softwares for such task. For example autoremesher or instant meshes (which are free to use) or paid alternatives for a better experience.

Comment: @Gorgious I downloaded them and I'll try them later and get back to you. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is good topology for 2D anim depends on how this animation should looks like. There is many technique and styles so for example you can try

### CutOut animation

model cut into several parts driven manually or armature. For this kind there is awesome addon [Cut-Out Animation Tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRVnk1PMDTs), that make it very easy to work with (includes script to generate parts from Photoshop or Inkscape layers in proper position and ready to import to blender with click to generate armature).

### Grease Pencil

Very powerful anim tool set with many options of creation and animation, frame by frame, using sculpt mode , or armature as well ... [example one of many](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMv5i8QJ4ro)

### Delaunay Triangulation

For some kind of animation could be helpful to use triangulated topology. There was a script for Blender 2.49 that I can't even find. But similar feature is a part of great *BlenderGIS* addon, but it doesn't generate point cloud for triangulation (as the old one) it just connects the points. So to get Delaunay work you have to generate a point cloud first.

I'm sure there has to be a simple script that can do this in a one click, but in meantime here is one solution ...

- Download, install, enable [BlenderGIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) addon
- Select *SVG* curve convert to mesh like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> **Visual Geometry to Mesh**

[image]

- In *Geometry Node* editor add **New**, add *Point Distribution* node type **Poisson Disk** and merge original mesh with points by *Join Geometry* node as shown bellow

[image]

- **Apply** *Geometry Node* modifier under *Properties editor > Modifiers*
- Search for **GIS Delaunay** (or go to 3D view editor top row menu *> GIS > Mesh > Delaunay*)

[image]

Notes:

- Poison Disk can be generated also by addon Point Cloud Visualizer
- Delaunay can be generated also by Archipack addon under Terrain
- or there was a [Point Cloud Skinner](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/jKu98lH9kWjCNUQl0Oe7B1tM1nQ.zip) addon, but v0.18 works only for blender 2.83 not 2.9x
- I saw some [technique](https://youtu.be/MwANWf6G9EE) of delaunay triangulation based on Voronoi pattern (out of blender)
- 